# PHP, Replace all occurrences of page=number

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, query-string, str-replace

I need to remove all occurences of &page=* from a string, where * is a number. How would I do that with regexp(?)

So far I've been using,

```
$this->targetpage = str_replace('&page='.$this->page, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo .$this->targetpage;
```

Also a bonus would be to not have to include the &, as the page=something could also be after the "?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->targetpage = preg_replace('~((?<=\?)page=\d+&?|&page=\d+)~i', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: I think it should be `~[&?]...` in the front, this way it says "one or zero `&`" not "one `&` or `?`".

Comment: @complex857 I removed [&?] because that would mean it will remove the ?, which means the url will be invalid.

Comment: Hmm, that's true, however this matches `somepage=1` as well now, and replaces it to `some`. Maybe lookahead with `~(?<=&|\?)page=\d+~` ? (still will leave marks `?` or `&`)

Comment: Yeah, that's also true. I edited the regex so it will either remove page=34& if it's prefixed with a ?, and &page=34 otherwise

Comment: If you change the 2 instances of `\d+` to `\d*` this will also pick up occurrences `page=` ie no number